# switch statement using char in the case condition?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a switch statement that uses a char to represent each case. In my textbook the examples show I can use a char to do this but when I compile my program I get this:

```
    StudentInvoiceListMenuApp.java:54: error: incompatible types
        case 'R':
             ^
    required: String
    found:    char
    1 error
```

This is my code:

```
    switch (inputCode) {

        case 'R':
            System.out.println("\nEnter file name:");
            fileName = menuApp.nextLine();
            if (inputCode.trim().length() == 0) {
                break; // no file name entered
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `inputCode` is of type `String`, not `char`... so if you're using Java 7, you just want to change it to:

```
case "R":
```

Alternatively, change the type of `inputCode` to `char`, making appropriate adjustments elsewhere. (If you're not using Java 7, this would be your only option - but I suspect you *are* using Java 7, as otherwise you'd get a different compiler error.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inputCode is a string. If you want to look at the first element of the string you should do:

```
switch (inputCode[0]) {
```

If you want to compare with a single character string you should do:

```
case "R":
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputCode` seems instance of `String` and you are trying to compare it with `char`,

String in switch is supported with and  after java -7

Answer (score 0):

`inputCode` is a String instance.